# GoogleSheet AppScript loop does not terminate its execution

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've implemented the following simple function for my google spreadsheet. The function gets a range from the first row until the last edited row and then checks the months between each row. where a change is found the border is bolded otherwise canceled. This function is called in the 'onOpen' function, then it runs at the sheet startup.

```
function cashflow_drawMonthBorder()
{
  let first_date_row = 3 // first row in the range
  let last_date_row
  let sh, dd, r, str

  sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName( "Flussi" )
  dd = new Date()

  last_date_row = sh.getLastRow()
  dd = sh.getRange( 1, 1, last_date_row ).getValues()
  
  for( r = last_date_row - 1; r >= first_date_row; r-- )
  {
    //SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast( `row ${r}, lastrow ${last_date_row}`, "Info" )
    //Logger.log("%d - %d, %d - %d", r-1, dd[r-1][0].getMonth(), r, dd[r][0].getMonth())

    if( dd[r - 1][0].getMonth() != dd[r][0].getMonth() )
    {
      sh.getRange( r, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn() ).
          setBorder( null, null, true, null, null, null, 'black',
          SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM )
    }
    else if( sh.getRange( r, 1 ).getBorder().getBottom() != 'false' )
    {
      sh.getRange( r, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn() ).setBorder(
                   null, null, false, null, null, null )
    }
    else
    {
      ;
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I've a range of 100 rows: it happens that the for loop processes only a certain amount of the range's rows, then stops. However, if I run the script from the editor the loop iterates over all the 100 rows.

Do you know the reason of such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
function cashflow_drawMonthBorder() {
  let first_date_row = 3; // first row in the range
  let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Flussi");
  let dd = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  for (let r = sh.getLastRow() - 1; r >= first_date_row; r--) {
    if (dd[r - 1][0].getMonth() !== dd[r][0].getMonth()) {
      sh.getRange(r, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, 'black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
    } else if (sh.getRange(r, 1).getBorder().getBottom() !== SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM) {
      sh.getRange(r, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).setBorder(null, null, false, null, null, null);
    } else {
      break; // Exit the loop if no border is set
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MFrancone try. this

Comment: I don't understand what's the big difference, but the implementation you provided does not solve the issue. It seems that it's only a matter of time: after 30seconds the script is stopped. On the other end, if I run the script from the editor, the foor loop goes all the way through the iterations.

Comment: I found the problem: simple triggers have some restriction, amonst that the following
_They cannot run for longer than 30 seconds._